# Sumtotal in ReportViewer

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, report, reportviewer

```
+----------+------------+------+------+--------------+---------+---------+
|          |    SUBJ    |  MIN |  MAX |    RESULT    | STATUS  | PERCENT |
|          +------------+------+------+--------------+---------+---------+
|          |  Subj1     |   35 |  100 |        13    |  FAIL   |  13.00% |
|EXAM NAME |  Subj2     |   35 |  100 |        63    |  PASS   |  63.00% |
|          |  Subj3     |   35 |  100 |        35    |  PASS   |  35.00% |
|          +------------+------+------+--------------+---------+---------+
|          |  Total     |  105 |  300 |       111    |  PASS   |  37.00% |
+----------+------------+------+------+--------------+---------+---------+
```

This is my report viewer report format.The SubTotal row counts the
 total of all the above column.Every thing is fine. But in the status
 column its showing Pass. I want it to show fail if there is single
 fail in the status column. I am generating Status if Result < Min then
 it is fail or else it is pass. Now how to change the SubTotal row
 below depending upon the condition. And is there any way to show the
 Subtotal row directly from database. Any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to use custom code (right-click non-display area of report, choose Properties and click the Code tab) - calculate the pass/fail score in the detail, display it in the group footer and reset it in the group header:

```
Dim PassFail As String

// Reset Pass or Fail status in group header
Public Function ResetAndDisplayStatusTitle() AS String
    PassFail = "PASS" // Initialise status to pass
    ResetAndDisplayStatusTitle = "Status"
End Function

// Calculate pass/fail on each detail row and remember any fails
Public Function CalculatePassFail() As String
    Dim ThisResult As String

    // Calculate whether this result is pass or fail
    If Fields!Result.Value < Fields!Min.Value Then
        ThisResult = "FAIL"
    Else
        ThisResult ="PASS"
    End If

    // Remember any failure as overall failure
    If ThisResult = "FAIL" Then PassFail = "FAIL"

    CalculatePassFail = ThisResult
End Function
```

Then you tie in the custom code to your cells in your table as follows:

In the value for the status column in your group header you put:

```
=Code.ResetAndDisplayStatusTitle()
```

In the value for the status column in the detail row you put:

```
=Code.CalculatePassFail()
```

In the value for the status column in the group footer you put:

```
=Code.PassFail
```

With respect to getting the subtotal row from the database directly from the database, there are a couple of ways depending on what result you are after.

- Join the detail row to a subtotalling row in your SQL (so that the subtotal fields appear on every row in the dataset) and use those fields.
- Again, use custom code (but this is probably overly complicated for subtotalling)

However, these tricks are only for strange circumstances and in general the normal out-of-the-box subtotalling can be tweaked to give the result you are after. If there is something specific you want to know, it is probably best to explain the problem in a separate question so that issue can be dealt with individually.